# Funciones básicas en python 3.6 no reconoce Intrucciones dentro de while

Tags: python, python-3.x

Saludos , necesito de su ayuda, tengo este algoritmo Básico , que llama funciones tipo void , el problema es que no me sigue las instrucciones del menú, al ejecutarlo solo aparece el print  y se ejecuta el while sin prestar atencion a la respuesta. y no encuentro la causa. 
mi código es este:

```
def circulo():
    radio = (input("Ingrese le valor del radio: "))
    radio = radio * radio
    print("El area del circulo es ", radio)    

def cuadrado():
    lado = input("Ingrese le valor del un lado: ")
    lado = lado * lado
    print("El area del circulo es ", lado)

def triangulo():
    triangulo = input("Ingrese le valor del radio: ")
    triangulo = triangulo * 0.5
    print("El area del circulo es ", triangulo)

menu = True
while menu == True:
    resp = input("Bienvenido \n Ingrese el valor de  la operacion que desea realizar \n 1.- circulo \n 2.- cuadrado \n 3.- triangulo \n 4.-Salir")
if resp == 1:
    circulo()
elif resp==2:
    cuadrado()
elif resp==3:
    triangulo()
elif resp==4:
    menu==False
else:
    print("Ingrese una opcion valida")
```

Comment: la identacion en python es MUY IMPORTANTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta que en python es muy importante el identado del código, a continuación cito textualmente:

> Las funciones de Python no tienen begin o end explícitos, ni llaves
>   que marquen dónde empieza o termina su código. El único delimitador
>   son dos puntos (:) y el sangrado del propio código.

Por si deseas indagar un poco mas aquí te anexo enlace [Su primer programa en python](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python/Su_primer_programa_en_Python/Sangrado_(indentado)_de_c%C3%B3digo).

```
def circulo():
    radio = (input("Ingrese le valor del radio: "))
    radio = radio * radio
    print("El diámetro del circulo es ", radio)    

def cuadrado():
    lado = input("Ingrese le valor del un lado: ")
    lado = lado * lado
    print("El área del circulo es ", lado)

def triangulo():
    triangulo = input("Ingrese le valor de la base: ")
    triangulo = triangulo * 0.5
    print("El área de este triangulo especial es ", triangulo)

menu = True
while menu == True:
    resp = int(input("\nBienvenido \n Ingrese el valor de  la operacion que desea realizar \n 1.- diámetro de circulo \n 2.- área de un cuadrado \n 3.- área de un triangulo especial \n 4.-Salir"))
    if resp == 1:
        circulo()
    elif resp == 2:
        cuadrado()
    elif resp == 3:
        triangulo()
    elif resp == 4:
        menu = False
    else:
        print("Ingrese una opción valida")
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: NekoOs hay otro error que va ha hacer que siga sin funcionarle (de hecho puede que la identación sea solo un problema al copiar el código), `input` en Python 3 (por la etiqueta y los prints es la versión que usa) retorna una cadena y el en los condicionales compara con un entero, por lo que no va a entrar  en ninguna jamás. Hay que hacer la comparación con un str (`if resp == "1": ...`) o hacer casting a la variable (`resp = int(input("...."))`). Añade esto a la respuesta si quieres, para que quede correcta. Saludos.

Comment: @FJSevilla anexe el casting para garantizar el funcionamiento, sin embargo he de decir que instale python 3 y el código posteado funciono correctamente.

Comment: Te aseguro que sin el casting no funciona (`input` retorna un objeto `str`  en Python 3 y una cadena nunca va a ser igual a un entero). ¿Estás seguro que lo ejecutas el código con el intérprete de Python 3 y no con el 2? Ten en cuenta que aunque tengas ambos intérpretes instalados el código se ejecuta con el que tenga tu sistema por defecto, si no especificas lo contrario. En Python 2 si funciona porque input evalua código Pyton válido y retorna en este caso un entero (aunque es peligorso usar input así en py2). Error no da, solo que no va a reconocer las opciones y entra siempre en el `else`.

Comment: +1 @FJSevilla Aun cuando instale propiamente python 3, parece que al momento de instalar una herramienta para la edición de código esta incluyo la versión 2.7.12 de la cual no me había percatado, igualmente ya había realizado la corrección en la respuesta.

Comment: NekoOs , FJsevilla   Muchas Gracias a ambos , de hecho lo sugerido por los dos la indentacion , y la conversión de dato string a entero era lo que me estaba causando problemas, se me hace un poco extraño porque ya me había acostumbrado a las laves en java.